# How to resolve method name conflict in VS2012 Fakes framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, shim, microsoft-fakes

I am using VS2012 Fakes and MSTEST framework to do unit test. I have a third party dll and I need to fake it. However there is a method (getItemAt(int)) in the dll that seems to conflict with a method that exits in Fakes.

The error message I get during compile is:

> **Error   2** The type 'MyObject.Fakes.ShimList' already contains a
>   definition for 'get_ItemAtInt32'
>   [D:\Dev\Test\obj\Debug\Fakes\o\f.csproj]  D:\Dev\Teste\f.cs   6933    111 Test

Any solution to pass by this error to continue work with Fakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the Fakes code generator breaks when trying to generate a shim for MyObject.List class in this third-party library. Could you submit this at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio? In the meantime, you can use the approach described  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx#bkmk_type_filtering) to generate only those stubs and shims you actually plan to use. Hopefully, that does not include the MyObject.List class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solved my problem by using ShimGeneration filter.